# Ncurses mvwprintw doesnt print

Tags: c++, ncurses

I have a simple program that has a main window and a small window on the bottom like (without the lines, thats just so you can see the two windows:

```
+------------------+
|                  |
|                  | 
|                  |
+------------------+
|                  |
+------------------+
```

I want the bottom area to be a place where you can type in, and here is my source code:

```cpp
#include <termios.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
int main()
{
    int scrx;
    int scry;

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    clear();
    raw();

    getmaxyx(stdscr, scrx, scry);
    WINDOW* input = newwin(1, scrx, scry, 0);

    std::string cmdbuf;

    while(true)
    {
        int newx;
        int newy;
        getmaxyx(stdscr, newx, newy);

        if(newx != scrx || newy != scry)
        {
            // do stuff;
        }

        char c = wgetch(input);
        cmdbuf.push_back(c);
        werase(input);

        mvwprintw(input, 0, 0, cmdbuf.c_str());
        refresh();
        wrefresh(input);
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to print anything, just move my cursor (which gets suck halfway across the screen). How can I make it so that text actually gets printed and that my cursor actually moves across the full screen?

Comment: You’re erasing within the while loop rather than just before it. You’re not actually using newx & newy. Take a look at the following: http://www6.uniovi.es/cscene/CS3/CS3-08.html

Comment: @Geoff I have tried commenting the werase line, it doesn't seem to help

Comment: And newx & newy are not used...

Comment: @Geoff Yes, they are not used, but that's only for when the window is resized (which, in my testing never happened)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tidied it up for you a bit. Press 'q' to quit. You get the idea.

```
#include <termios.h>                                                                                                                                                                         
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
  int scrx, scry;
  initscr();
  getmaxyx(stdscr, scry, scrx);
  WINDOW *w = newwin(1, scrx, scry - 1, 0);
  std::string cmdbuf {};
  char c = '\0';

  while (c != 'q')
  {
    int newx, newy;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, newx, newy);

    if(newx != scrx || newy != scry)
    {
      // do stuff;
    }

    c = wgetch(w);
    cmdbuf += c;
    mvwprintw(w, 0, 0, "%s", cmdbuf.c_str());
    wrefresh(w);
  }

  delwin(w);
  endwin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `newwin` is:

```
WINDOW *newwin(
         int nlines, int ncols,
         int begin_y, int begin_x);
```

You are calling:

```
newwin(1,scry,scrx,0)
```

Which sets the size of you window to `1` tall and `scry` wide, and puts it at coordinates (`0`,`srcx`). What you want is:

```
newwin(1,scry,scrx-1,0)
```

Where `1` is the height of the window.

Also, `cbreak` overrides `raw`, so there is no point to calling both.

Answer (score 0):

The `refresh` is overwriting the `mvwprintw` because they're different windows.  For the given example, there's no reason to refresh *`stdscr`* because nothing (except for the `initscr` call) has updated that window.  Moving `refresh` out of the loop would help (but the "do stuff" can obviously interfere with that).

The newx/newy logic is too fragmentary to comment on (I'd use [`getbegyx`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getyx.3x.html) ...).

Comment: newx/newy logic is for screen resizes